# Page post login blocked for waiting for listen sockets in PHP

Tags: php, html, sockets, server

After login block the page for which this waiting(listen) for connections. Because it does not show the page post login in html?

**ServerSocket.php**

```
<?php 
namespace proyectodam\Lib;

class ServerSocket{
    private $address;
    private $port;

    public function __construct($address, $port){
        set_time_limit(0);
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init(){
        // Create a TCP Stream socket
        $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // 0 for  SQL_TCP
        // Bind the socket to an address/port
        socket_bind($sock, 0, $this->port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost
        // Start listening for connections
        socket_listen($sock);

        //loop and listen
        while(true){
          /* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
          $client = socket_accept($sock);
          //$_SESSION[socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555)] = socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555);
          // Read the input  from the client – 1024000 bytes
          //$input = socket_read($client, 1024000);

          // from here you need to do your database stuff
          // and handle the response 

           // Display output  back to client
          socket_write($client, $response.'\n');
          socket_close($client);
        }
        // Close the master sockets
        socket_close($sock);
    }
}
```

**In the page post login**

```
<?php
namespace\proyectodam\Lib;
new ServerSocket('127.0.0.1', 5555);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
.............................
</html>
```

**ClienteSocket.java**

```
public class ClienteSocket{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            //wr.write("data");
            //wr.flush();
            System.out.println(in.readLine());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Because I cannot see the HTML post login?

Comment: I want the server is set to listen after logging in, because it blocked?
how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you meaning with "HTML post login", but the php script is blocked until a connection is accepted, and this prevents the page to be sent to the browser.